# Superselection and Position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, superposition, quantum-states

For simplicity, let me assume that space is 1-dimensional and the position observable has countably many orthogonal eigenstates. Then the operator $\sum_{i}|x_i\rangle\langle x_i|$ would be an observable that can tell us whether the state of a system can be expressed in terms of some linear combination of position eigenstates.

Suppose, for the sake of argument, that for some state $|\Psi\rangle$, the following holds:

$\sum_{i}|x_i\rangle\langle x_i|\Psi\rangle = 0$.

So, I take it, the system at issue is not 'in space' in any meaningful sense.

Now, is it still possible that $\langle x_i|A|\Psi\rangle \neq 0$ for some position eigenstae $|x_i\rangle$ and some observable $A$?

Or does  $\sum_{i}|x_i\rangle\langle x_i|\Psi\rangle = 0$ entail $\langle x_i|A|\Psi\rangle = 0$ for any $|x_i\rangle$ and $A$?

While I took the position operator as an example, I think the question can be a general one: If the state of a system $|\Psi\rangle$ cannot be given by any linear combination of the eigenstates of an observable $O$, is $|\Psi\rangle$ separated from *any* eigenstate of $O$ by a superselection rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full sum $\sum_i \left | x_i \right > \left < x_i \right | = 1$ is the identity operator. Every wavefunction (except spin half parts) can be expressed in terms of that. If not, that thing falls out of Hilbert space and is thus not a quantum state.

Position is actually kind of bad for this kind of thought analysis. Momentum is at least the energy eigenstates for free particles, and could be easier to imagine.

Consider a beam of particles, photons or electrons, incident upon a state $\left | \psi \right >$ of nothingness in its path. Then for the part of the momentum wavefunction far off the beam's direction, partial sum $\sum_i \left | k_i \right > \left < k_i \mid \psi \right > = 0 $, but we can have an interaction $A$, say, that introduces a target into the path of the beam. Then the same partial sum $\sum_i \left | k_i \right > \left < k_i \mid A \mid \psi \right > \neq 0$

If an operator corresponds to an observable, then the operator is not just Hermitian, it is also having a complete basis. Failure to be expressible by any linear combination of the eigenstates of said operator would mean that you don't have a quantum state at all. You can only say that you are considering something that is orthogonal to a subset of the eigenstates of some observable operator, not the whole eigenspace, because the whole eigenspace is the complete Hilbert space itself.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. I think I ignore the fact that the eigenstates of an observable forms a complete orthonormal basis. When you said " the operator is not just Hermitian, it is also having a complete basis" did you mean that some Hermitian operators don't have this property and thus cannot represent observables? Or were you just emphasizing a general property of all Hermitian operators?

Comment: I am not mathematically sophisticated to know if it were proved, so I was trying to leave open the possibility of the existence of Hermitian operators that do not have a complete basis. But in quantum theory, we simply postulate that physical observables have both properties. Now, this is only relevant for infinite cases, because it was proved that for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, Hermitian operators have complete orthonormal bases. The lack of a proof for the inifinite case is the reason why it was postulated. The postulate has yet to cause us problems.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Based on what you said in your answer, is it safe to assume that for any state $|\psi\rangle$ in Hilbert space, there is some position eigenstate $|x_k \rangle$ and some observable $O$ such that $\langle x_k|O|\psi\rangle \neq 0$? Is this condition just trivially equivalent to $|\psi\rangle$ being in Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes, I think so.